# learn mean and dispersion parameter of a loss function using keras R

Tags: r, keras, neural-network

I am trying to write a model in keras with the following architecture:

[Neural Network architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lVpC.png).

Note that the dispersion parameter is independent of the input. My attempt for the dispersion was to simply feed a dummy covariate always taking the value 1, and remove the bias from the layer. Can anyone please direct me to the correct documentation or perhaps provide an example of the correct way of doing this? Thank you very much.

Please see my attempt below.

```
library(keras)

Y_claims_train = as.numeric(rpois(100, 1))
X_mat_train = data.matrix(rnorm(100))

logdensity_tensor <- function (y , mu , phi ) {
  # Negative Binomial loss
  y * k_log ( k_maximum(1e-5 , mu )) - (y + phi ) * k_log ( mu + phi )
  
}
dev_loss <- function ( y_true , y_pred ) {
  mu = y_pred[1]
  phi = y_pred[2]
  2 * ( logdensity_tensor ( y = y_true , mu = y_true , phi = phi ) - 
          logdensity_tensor ( y = y_true , mu = mu , phi = phi ))
  
}



DesignShapeNN = ncol(X_mat_train)


# Mean part
Features  <- layer_input(shape = c(DesignShapeNN), dtype = 'float32', name = 'Features') 

Network <- list(Features) %>% layer_concatenate(name = 'concat_NN' ) %>% 
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'tanh', name = 'layer1') %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'tanh', name = 'layer2') %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'tanh', name = 'layer3') %>%
    layer_dense(units = 1, activation = 'softplus', name = 'ok')

# dispersion part
phis <- layer_input(shape = 1, dtype = 'float32', name = 'phi') 

phi_network = list(phis) %>% layer_concatenate(name = 'concat_phi' ) %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "softmax", name = 'phi_softmax', trainable = T, use_bias = F ) 



# dummy dispersion covariates
X_mat_phi = data.matrix((rep(1, nrow(X_mat_train))))


model_deep <- keras_model(inputs = c(Features, phis), outputs = c(Network, phi_network))


model_deep %>% compile(
  loss = dev_loss,
  optimizer = 'nadam'
)



fit <- model_deep %>% fit(
  list(X_mat_train, X_mat_phi),
  as.numeric(Y_claims_train),
  epochs = 5,
  verbose = T)
```